# Npm Error :- Windows NT - How to resolve

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I get the following error when I try npm install :

```
E:\project\nodeJS\sws-nodejs-angular>npm install
npm WARN install Couldn't install optional dependency: Unsupported
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v5.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.6
npm ERR! Cannot read property 'localeCompare' of undefined
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     E:\project\nodeJS\sws-nodejs-angular\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: It looks like the OS is not supported. Assuming 32-Bit right? Is it a virtual machine?

Comment: are you trying to install angular.js?

Answer (score 0):

The previous message you mentioned

```
npm WARN install Couldn't install optional dependency: Unsupported
```

is printed when you run `install`.

it calls `npm-cli.js` and uses `deps.js` to load dependencies (`loadDeps`).

it checks for errors and calls `function andHandleOptionalErrors` which seems to fail here since `isFatal` is most likely `True`

```
var isFatal = failedDependency(tree, name)
```

After that it writes the error you saw previously

For every dependency it checks and runs `function andForEachChild` which seems to call `localeCompare` to check the package dependency

```
return aa[1].package.name.localeCompare(bb[1].package.name)
```

I am not sure, but the optional dependency that is parsed from your locale is probably related to `Windows_NT 6.1.7601` and `deps.js` is calling `log` to print out the `"ERR!"` output. `package.name` is probably not defined due to a dependency not being supported.

tldr; either the OS or another dependency is not supported.